# Server 2016 Tacacs.net install throwing "Error in Processing response" and need it to be up today.

Tags: cisco, windows-server-2016, tacacs+

I've been struggling a few days with this. I have a brand new server that I install tacacs.net on and I can't get it to work. I followed the quickstart guide and opened port 49.

I'm thinking either there is an error with the character set or an issue with domain hardening. I know we have all old Cyphers disabled and we only use aes128 and 256 as well as having fips compliance applied and tls1.2 enabled and working.

Using Tacacs.net version 1.3.2
Server 2016 (meets requirements including .net 2.0)
All files have read-only removed.

[Cmd Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwRmP.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to have been fips compliance. Not sure why but when I removed the gpo from the ou for the server I was able to authenticate.

Any ideas what part isn't compatible with fips?